# Pandas - Merge of Dataframe with a Series Values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe (doc2) which basically looks like:

```
  Index     AgeGroups     Factor Cancer
    0        0_5  wo-statin    Yes
    1       6_10  wo-statin    Yes
    2      11_15  wo-statin    Yes
    3      16_20  wo-statin    Yes
    4      21_25  wo-statin    Yes
    5      26_30  wo-statin    Yes
    6      31_35  wo-statin    Yes
    7      36_40  wo-statin    Yes
    8      41_45  wo-statin    Yes
    9      46_50  wo-statin    Yes
    10     51_55  wo-statin    Yes
    11     56_60  wo-statin    Yes
    12     61_65  wo-statin    Yes
    13     66_70  wo-statin    Yes
    14     71_75  wo-statin    Yes
    15     76_80  wo-statin    Yes
    16     81_85  wo-statin    Yes
    17     86_90  wo-statin    Yes
    18     91_95  wo-statin    Yes
    19    96_100  wo-statin    Yes
```

And a Series (frame_concat) :

```
Index         0
0_5           0
6_10          0
11_15         0
16_20         2
21_25         1
26_30         4
31_35         1
36_40         2
41_45         4
46_50         5
51_55         5
56_60         2
61_65         3
66_70         3
71_75         2
76_80         0
81_85         0
86_90         0
91_95         0
96_100        0
```

Now, basically I want to merge both (doc2 , frame_concat) in such a way that (AgeGroups from doc2 = index from frame_concat) And Perhaps a new Column lets call it Frequency which contains values

```
0
0
0
0
2
1
4
1
2
4
5
5
2
3
3
2
0
0
0
0
0
```

Expecting to get a result as a whole like this :

```
Index     AgeGroups     Factor Cancer   Frequency
        0        0_5  wo-statin    Yes    0
        1       6_10  wo-statin    Yes    0
        2      11_15  wo-statin    Yes    0
        3      16_20  wo-statin    Yes    2
        4      21_25  wo-statin    Yes    1
        5      26_30  wo-statin    Yes    4
        6      31_35  wo-statin    Yes    1
        7      36_40  wo-statin    Yes    2
        8      41_45  wo-statin    Yes    4
        9      46_50  wo-statin    Yes    5
        10     51_55  wo-statin    Yes    5
        11     56_60  wo-statin    Yes    2
        12     61_65  wo-statin    Yes    3
        13     66_70  wo-statin    Yes    3
        14     71_75  wo-statin    Yes    2
        15     76_80  wo-statin    Yes    0
        16     81_85  wo-statin    Yes    0
        17     86_90  wo-statin    Yes    0
        18     91_95  wo-statin    Yes    0
        19    96_100  wo-statin    Yes    0
```

I am thankful for any help provided :) . Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [170]: doc2.merge(frame_concat.to_frame('Frequency'), left_on='AgeGroups',
                     right_index=True, how='left')
Out[170]:
      AgeGroups     Factor Cancer  Frequency
Index
0           0_5  wo-statin    Yes          0
1          6_10  wo-statin    Yes          0
2         11_15  wo-statin    Yes          0
3         16_20  wo-statin    Yes          2
4         21_25  wo-statin    Yes          1
5         26_30  wo-statin    Yes          4
6         31_35  wo-statin    Yes          1
7         36_40  wo-statin    Yes          2
8         41_45  wo-statin    Yes          4
9         46_50  wo-statin    Yes          5
10        51_55  wo-statin    Yes          5
11        56_60  wo-statin    Yes          2
12        61_65  wo-statin    Yes          3
13        66_70  wo-statin    Yes          3
14        71_75  wo-statin    Yes          2
15        76_80  wo-statin    Yes          0
16        81_85  wo-statin    Yes          0
17        86_90  wo-statin    Yes          0
18        91_95  wo-statin    Yes          0
19       96_100  wo-statin    Yes          0
```

Comment: MaxU, thank you first of all for the reply. For the first option, it gave me InvalidIndexError : Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects and for the second option it gives me TypeError :'numpy.int64' object not callable. I am sorry :)

Comment: @Aceraceae, what is the output of `type(frame_concat)` and `frame_concat.dtypes; doc2.dtypes`

Comment: type (frame_concat) : pandas.core.series.Series ; type(frame_concat.dtypes) : numpy.dtype and type(doc2.dtypes) :  pandas.core.series.Series . Thank you so much for your time

Comment: @Aceraceae, i need an output of: `print(doc2.dtypes)`

Comment: print (doc2.dtypes) :AgeGroups  : object, Factor: object, Cancer: object , dtype : object

Comment: you are absolutely awesome ! Thank you so much MaxU

Comment: @Aceraceae, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

what about simple?

```
doc2['Frequency'] = frame_concat
```